# Can't find file executable in your configured search path for gnc gcc compiler

Tags: gcc, codeblocks

My problem is that code::blocks error message tells me that it can't find file executable    in the search path for `gnc gcc` compiler. Although, I don't know what that means. Also I  typed out some code:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main(void) {
    cout <<"Hello World" <<endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

I can't build it or run in `code::blocks`. What do I need to do?

I went on line but I   got some answers that are way over my head. I was able to use code::blocks once before I installed `Visual studios express 2013`. `Visual studios` didn't work right either. It kept asking me to repair or uninstall every time I tried to open it. So I deleted it along with `code::blocks`. Now that I re-installed `code::blocks` I still can't get to work right.

This problem with compilers is taking up all my time and I can't practice learning programming because I can't get any compiler to work right. I need some help, please.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I'm guessing you've installed Code::Blocks but not installed or set up GCC yet. I'm assuming you're on Windows, based on your comments about Visual Studio; if you're on a different platform, the steps for setting up GCC should be similar but not identical.

First you'll need to download GCC. There are lots and lots of different builds; personally, I use the 64-bit build of [TDM-GCC](http://tdm-gcc.tdragon.net/download). The setup for this might be a bit more complex than you'd care for, so you can go for the 32-bit version or just grab a preconfigured Code::Blocks/TDM-GCC setup [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe).

Once your setup is done, go ahead and launch Code::Blocks. You don't need to create a project or write any code yet; we're just here to set stuff up or double-check your setup, depending on how you opted to install GCC.

Go into the `Settings` menu, then select `Global compiler settings` in the sidebar, and select the `Toolchain executables` tab. Make sure the `Compiler's installation directory` textbox matches the folder you installed GCC into. For me, this is `C:\TDM-GCC-64`. Your path will vary, and this is completely fine; just make sure the path in the textbox is the same as the path you installed to. Pay careful attention to the warning note Code::Blocks shows: this folder must have a `bin` subfolder which will contain all the relevant GCC executables. If you look into the folder the textbox shows and there isn't a `bin` subfolder there, you probably have the wrong installation folder specified.

Now, in that same `Toolchain executables` screen, go through the individual `Program Files` boxes one by one and verify that the filenames shown in each are correct. You'll want some variation of the following:

- C compiler: `gcc.exe` (mine shows `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe`)
- C++ compiler: `g++.exe` (mine shows `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`)
- Linker for dynamic libs: `g++.exe` (mine shows `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe`)
- Linker for static libs: `gcc-ar.exe` (mine shows `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar.exe`)
- Debugger: `GDB/CDB debugger: Default`
- Resource compiler: `windres.exe` (mine shows `windres.exe`)
- Make program: `make.exe` (mine shows `mingw32-make.exe`)

Again, note that all of these files are in the `bin` subfolder of the folder shown in the `Compiler installation folder` box - if you can't find these files, you probably have the wrong folder specified. It's okay if the filenames aren't a perfect match, though; different GCC builds might have differently prefixed filenames, as you can see from my setup.

Once you're done with all that, go ahead and click `OK`. You can restart Code::Blocks if you'd like, just to confirm the changes will stick even if there's a crash (I've had occasional glitches where Code::Blocks will crash and forget any settings changed since the last launch).

Now, you should be all set. Go ahead and try your little section of code again. You'll want `int main(void)` to be `int main()`, but everything else looks good. Try building and running it and see what happens. It should run successfully.

Comment: I do all, then I create a project, I choose my newly configured compiler. When I look Make Commands in Build options, it still has command from another compiler, not mine, and compiles with other compiler.

Comment: Thanks, it was great, however I did all steps suggested by you but again I got the same warning: Can't find file executable in your .... until I click on Auto-detect button in Toolchain executable tab and the problem fixed forever!

Answer (score 42):

Just open your setting->compiler and click on the reset defaults and it will start work.

Answer (score 13):

*** How to Download and install CodeBlocks.*** ( I have already downloaded )

---

***How to solve the CodeBlocks environment error.

1. Go to "Settings"----"Compiler"----"Selected compiler"( GNU GCC Compiler ).
2. Then, Selected "Toolchain executables".
3. Now,  "( C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW )"

See Video : https://youtu.be/Tb1VnXs60Lg

Comment: This video is also very helpful: https://youtu.be/17RazgwROAg

Answer (score 8):

I had also found this error but I have solved this problem by easy steps. If you want to solve this problem follow these steps:

**Step 1:** First start code block

**Step 2:** Go to menu bar and click on the **Setting** menu

**Step 3:** After that click on the **Compiler** option

**Step 4:** Now, a pop up window will be opened. In this window, select "**GNU GCC COMPILER**"

**Step 5:** Now go to the **toolchain executables** tab and select the compiler installation directory like **(C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin)**

**Step 6:** Click on the **Ok**.

[image]

Now you can remove this error by follow these steps. Sometimes you don't need to select bin folder. You need to select only **(C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW)** this path but some system doesn't work this path. That's why you have to select path from C:/ to bin folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For that you need to install binary of GNU GCC compiler, which comes with MinGW package. You can download MinGW( and put it under C:/ ) and later you have to download gnu -c, c++ related Binaries, so select required package and install them(in the MinGW ). Then in the Code::Blocks, go to  Setting, Compiler, ToolChain Executable. In that you will find Path, there set C:/MinGW.
Then mentioned error will be vanished.

Comment: Thanks. It starts compiler. But it shows press any key to continue, Whats the problem.

Answer (score 3):

- Uninstall/Remove your current codeblocks compiler.
- Install codeblocks using this link that contains *GCC* compiler files:   http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe.
- Now go to : Settings > Compiler.... > ToolChain Executables Tab
- CLICK on *Auto-detect* button and then click *OK* button. Now just restart CodeBlocks and start writing your codes and use the Build and run option. It will RUN normally.

Comment: Works for me on windows 7, 64 bit

Comment: @AlMamun Good to know :)

Answer (score 2):

Fistly, Code Blocks is not a compiler. It is just an integrated development environment.

So, you must show the path of your compiler at first, (if you dont have a compiler you have to download an install, it is not difficult to find. f.e. GCC is good one.)
If code blocks could not find automatically the path of compiler it is an obligation to show it yourself.

But when you install, probably Code Blocks automatically find your compiler.

Enjoy.

Answer (score 1):

This simple in below solution worked for me.
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=17336.0

I had a similar problem. Please note I'm a total n00b in C++ and IDE's but heres what I did (after some research)
So of course I downloaded the version that came with the compiler and it didn't work. Heres what I did:
1) go to settings in the upper part
2) click compiler
3) choose reset to defaults.

Hopefully this works

Answer (score 1):

I'm a total noob but I reinstalled over the codeblocks giving me these "Can't find file executable in your configured search path for gnc gcc compiler" errors by downloading:

**codeblocks-20.03mingw-setup.exe**

(IMPORTANT: make sure it has the "mingw" in the file download name, that has the compiler build that is required to compile the code which doesn't automatically comes with the main codeblocks editor software download because codeblocks already assumes you already have another compiler installed on your computer {visual studio 2019 or such}).

Then when I created a new project (console application) and used the defaults to quickly test it out.

It gave me **errors**.

So I went to Settings > Compiler > Selected Compiler set to: GNU GCC Compiler > Click on the "Tooolchain executables" tab > Click on Auto-Detect > Should say "**C:\Progam Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW**" >  Click OK.

Build and run a simple hello world code.

Should work! If not, look for the "**MingGW**" in the C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks and select it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way for Windows users.

1. Uninstall the existing codeblocks from your system.
2. Restart system.
3. Go to http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26
4. Download the **codeblocks-16.01mingw-setup.exe** file. It includes the GCC/G++ compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 4.9.2, 32 bit, SJLJ).

Comment: Installed that but had error about compiler. In settings path was C:/MINGW. Click Autodetect and it set correct path C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW