# CodeBlocks doesn't find compiler

Tags: c++, gcc, codeblocks

Suddenly CodeBlocks stopped working so I reinstalled it. Now it doesn't seem to find the compiler, no matter what i do. the message i get is"Can't find file executable in your configured search path for gnc gcc compiler". I have reset it do defaults countless times. I have downloaded the package with mingw, the one without, i have installed mingw separately and nothing. I have checked that the path is corect and i still get the error. I have followed the instructions here and still nothing: [Can't find file executable in your configured search path for gnc gcc compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254518/cant-find-file-executable-in-your-configured-search-path-for-gnc-gcc-compiler)
 any ideas on what i could do ? I am running windows 8.1.

Comment: Go to Settings > Compilers and debuggers and then select GCC. Could you show us your settings. 

Alternatively Code::Blocks has a version that you can download that has MingW included. Maybe reinstall that version?

Comment: I reset to defaults and then manually created the path it wanted (C:\HighTec\Msp430\MinGW\bin), then I manually selected all the components and it seems to work.