# Compile a C program gives "can't find compiler executable in your search path (GNU GCC compiler)" in Codeblocks

Tags: c, compilation, codeblocks

I have installed codeblocks in windows 7 first time and try to run a simple C program but I get this error?

> can't find compiler executable in your search path (GNU GCC compiler)

I tried many things to solve it but unable to compile.

Comment: Googling "*can't find compiler executable in your search path for gnu gcc compiler code blocks*" returns lots of solutions. Have you tried them?

Comment: Haven't found any proper solution .  :/

Comment: In that case, mention your attempts and the result.

Comment: well, just opened codeblocks. created a c project. wrote "hello world" codes then clicked "Run". but it shows that message.

Comment: First two hits on google: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=18075.0 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254518/cant-find-file-executable-in-your-configured-search-path-for-gnc-gcc-compiler

Comment: Is your issue solved? Got it working?

Comment: Thanks. problem solved. its working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the Mingw compiler or any other simiar compiler? If not install that first. After you have done so, you need to set codeblocks to use that compiler. You can do that by going to the `settings>compiler settings` and set the necessary options there. You may need to refer the place where you have installed Mingw or other compiler. Note the compiler executable is `gcc` for C and `g++` for C++ and the linker is `ld` i guess. Debugger is `gdb`. You need to tell codeblocks where are these located.

Answer (score 0):

I also received that error. I fixed it using Settings -> Compiler -> Global compiler settings -> Toolchain executables -> Auto detect.