# Codeblocks won't run executable

Tags: c++, codeblocks

somehow codeblocks decided not to run any new programs anymore. All I get is a black screen when running. Take for example the simple "Hello World" program. That will not even run. It compiles just fine without any error. All i see though when codeblocks opens is a black screen.

I tried looking online for help. It looked like this
[Can't find file executable in your configured search path for gnc gcc compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23254518/cant-find-file-executable-in-your-configured-search-path-for-gnc-gcc-compiler)
would fix the problem. It didn't though.

This was my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

cout<< "Hello World!" << endl;

return 0;
}
```

I don't know what happened and why. Sincerely hoping for an answer.

Comment: Try to reinstall codeblocks. Download the newest version with MinGW bundle included, then update the question if it won't fix

Comment: This has nothing to do with `compiler-construction`. Also, the compiler never runs programs, it merely compiles them.

Comment: What black screen are you talking about? The command prompt?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-line_interface

Comment: If you see the CMD you're probably not writing anything

Comment: If you aren't doing it already try also to add a `getchar()` to the end of the program if you see a black screen flashing and closing instantly.

If that won't work, try to insert a breakpoint and see if it pauses the program (if it does that it is running the program at least).

Also post your code so we can see if something is wrong

Comment: Have you tried to go in the folder using the command prompt and then excecute it typing its name?

Comment: Not sure how codeblocks works, but did you save your code before running it? If so, @Zorgatone 's idea is worth looking in to.

Comment: I think I am talking about the command prompt. (total noob in c++ or anything computer related). I dont really know how to use the command prompt to execute the program...

Comment: this sometimes caused by your Antivirus or the location of the project to much complex/wrong

Comment: Thank you all! It was apparently caused by my antivirus. Now i know where the problem lies I can try to fix it. Thanks again for all the trouble.